# How to create an animation of geospatial / temporal data

Tags: r, animation, time, geo

I have a set of data which contains around 150,000 observations of 800 subjects. Each observation has: subject ID, latitude, longitude, and the time that the subject was at those coordinates. The data covers a 24-hour period.

If I plot all the data at once I just get a blob. Is anyone able to give me some tips as to how I can animate this data so that I can observe the paths of the subjects as a function of time?

I've read the spacetime vignette but I'm not entirely sure it will do what I want. At this point I'm spending a whole lot of time googling but not really coming up with anything that meets my needs.

Any tips and pointers greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at the animation package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, but I will share how I have done this kind of animation in the past.

1. Create a function that plots all the subject locations for one time slice:

   ```
   plot_time = function(dataset, time_id) {
       # make a plot with your favorite plotting package (e.g. `ggplot2`)
       # Save it as a file on disk (e.g. using `ggsave`), under a regular name, 
       # frame001.png, frame002.png, see sprintf('frame%03d', time_index)
   }
   ```
2. Call this function on each of your timeslices, e.g. using `lapply`:

   ```
   lapply(start_time_id:stop_time_id, plot_time)
   ```

   leading to a set of graphics files on the hard drive called `frame001` to `framexxx`.
3. Use a tool to render those frames into a movie, e.g. using `ffmpeg`, see [for example](http://statisticalrecipes.blogspot.nl/2012/07/making-movie-out-of-images-png-using.html).

This is a general workflow, which has been already implemented in the `animation` package (thanks for reminding me @mdsummer). You can probably leverage that package to get your animation.

Comment: definitely use the animation package rather than your code to generate frames :)

Answer (score 3):

Here my first use of `animation` package.  It was easier than I anticipated and especially the `saveHTML` is really amazing. Here my scenario(even I think that my R-code will be clearer:)

1. I generate some data
2. I plot a basic plot for all persons as a background plot.
3. I reshape data to get to a wide format in a way I can plot an arrow between present and next position for each person.
4. I loop over hours , to generate many plots. I put the llop within the powerful `saveHTML` function.
5. You  get a html file with a nice animation. I show here one intermediate plot.

[image]

Here my code:

```
library(animation)
library(ggplot2)      
library(grid)
## creating some data of hours 
N.hour <- 24
dat <- data.frame(person=rep(paste0('p',1:3),N.hour),
                  lat=sample(1:10,3*N.hour,rep=TRUE),
                  long=sample(1:10,3*N.hour,rep=TRUE),
                  time=rep(1:N.hour,each=3))


# the base plot with
base <- ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=dat,aes(x=lat, y=long,colour = person),
             size=5)+ theme(legend.position = "none") 


## reshape data to lat and long formats

library(plyr)
dat.segs <- ddply(dat,.(person),function(x){
  dd <- do.call(rbind,
           lapply(seq(N.hour-1),
              function(y)c(y,x[x$time %in% c(y,y+1),]$lat,
                   x[x$time %in% c(y,y+1),]$long)))
  dd

})
colnames(dat.segs) <- c('person','path','x1','x2','y1','y2')

# a function to create the animation
oopt <- ani.options(interval = 0.5)
saveHTML({
  print(base)
  interval = ani.options("interval")
  for(hour in  seq(N.hour-1)){
    # a segment for each time
    tn <- geom_segment(aes(x= x1, y= y1, xend = x2,
                        yend = y2,colour = person), 
                       arrow = arrow(), inherit.aes = FALSE,
                       data =subset(dat.segs,path==hour))

    print(base <- base + tn)
    ani.pause()
  }
}, img.name = "plots", imgdir = "plots_dir", 
   htmlfile = "random.html", autobrowse = FALSE, 
    title = "Demo of animated lat/long for different persons",
    outdir=getwd())
```